# How to call a function inside a Javascript class (jQuery, jSuggest)

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I'm using the code found in this jsbin: http://jsbin.com/asahe5/10/edit

There is a function within that class called addItem, which adds an auto-suggested item to the page. However, there is no API built in to add something by clicking on a button for example.

I have tried the following, but it doesn't work (Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'addItem'):

```
var test = $("#test").jSuggest({
    source: 'http://example.com/page.php',
    minChars: 1,
    keyDelay: 200,
    selectedItemProp: 'name',
    seekVal: 'name',
    startText: 'Enter a country',
    newItem: false,
    newText: 'Please select a country from the list.',
    selectionAdded: function(elem, data){ add_country(data.value); },
    selectionRemoved: function(elem, data){ elem.fadeTo("fast", 0, function(){ elem.remove(); rem_country(data.value); }); }
});

function add_item(object, id) {
    test.addItem(object, id);
}
```

The most relevant part of the plugin:

```
(function($){

  $.fn.jSuggest = function(options) {
    var defaults = {
      source: {}, // Object or URL where jSuggest gets the suggestions from.
      uniqID: false,
      startText: 'Enter a Value', // Text to display when the jSuggest input field is empty.
      emptyText: 'No Results Found', // Text to display when their are no search results.
      preFill: {}, // Object from which you automatically add items when the page is first loaded.
      limitText: 'No More Values Are Allowed', // Text to display when the number of selections has reached it's limit.
      newItem: false, // If set to false, the user will not be able to add new items by any other way than by selecting from the suggestions list.
      newText: 'Adding New Values Is Not Allowed', // Text to display when the user tries to enter a new item by typing.
      selectedItemProp: 'value', // Value displayed on the added item
      selectProp: 'value', // Name of object property added to the hidden input.
      seekVal: 'value', // Comma separated list of object property names.
      queryParam: 'q', // The name of the param that will hold the search string value in the AJAX request.
      queryLimit: false, // Number for 'limit' param on ajax request.
      extraParams: '', // This will be added onto the end of the AJAX request URL. Make sure you add an '&' before each param.
      matchCase: false, // Make the search case sensitive when set to true.
      minChars: 1, // Minimum number of characters that must be entered before the search begins.
      keyDelay: 400, //  The delay after a keydown on the jSuggest input field and before search is started.
      resultsHighlight: true, // Option to choose whether or not to highlight the matched text in each result item.
      selectionLimit: false, // Limits the number of selections that are allowed.
      showResultList: true, // If set to false, the Results Dropdown List will never be shown at any time.
      selectionClick: function(elem){}, // Custom function that is run when a previously chosen item is clicked.
      selectionAdded: function(elem, data){}, // Custom function that is run when an item is added to the items holder.
      selectionRemoved: function(elem, data){ elem.remove(); }, // Custom function that is run when an item is removed from the items holder.
      spotFirst: true, // Option that spots the first suggestions on the results list if true.
      formatList: false, // Custom function that is run after all the data has been retrieved and before the results are put into the suggestion results list. 
      beforeRetrieve: function(string){ return string; }, // Custom function that is run before the AJAX request is made, or the local objected is searched.
      retrieveComplete: function(data){ return data; },
      resultClick: function(data){}, // Custom function that is run when a search result item is clicked.
      resultsComplete: function(){} // Custom function that is run when the suggestion results dropdown list is made visible.
    };  

    // Merge the options passed with the defaults.
    var opts = $.extend(defaults, options);     

    // Get the data type of the source.
    var dType = typeof opts.source;

.....................................

        function addItem(data, num) {

          // Add to the hidden input the seleced values property from the passed data.
          hiddenInput.val(hiddenInput.val()+data[opts.selectProp]+',');

          // If a selected item is clicked, add the selected class and call the custom selectionClick function.
          var item = $('<li class="as-selection-item" id="as-selection-'+num+'"></li>').click(function() {

            opts.selectionClick.call(this, $(this));
            itemsHolder.children().removeClass('selected');
            $(this).addClass('selected');

          });

          // If the close cross is clicked, 
          var close = $('<a class="as-close">x</a>').click(function() {

            // Remove the item from the hidden input.
            hiddenInput.val(hiddenInput.val().replace(data[opts.selectProp]+',',''));

            // Call the custom selectionRemoved function.
            opts.selectionRemoved.call(this, item, data);
            input.focus();
            return false;

          });

          // Insert the item with the selectedItemProp as text and the close cross.
          orgLI.before(item.html(data[opts.selectedItemProp]).prepend(close));

          // Call the custom selectionAdded function with the recently added item as elem and its associated data.
          opts.selectionAdded.call(this, orgLI.prev(), data);

        }

.....................................

      });

    }

  };

})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't call that function without changing the plugin to expose the function as a visible API.

Comment: How would I go about doing that? This is my first time using jQuery, so I'm still trying to grasp some of these things (and I've never used Javascript classes).

Comment: Well the first thing would be to figure out exactly what that function does, and what it expects its arguments to look like. The fact that the plugin doesn't (apparently) expose that functionality may suggest that it's somehow tricky to use without having access to the context that's there inside the plugin. Once you know that, you'd just have to figure out how to expose it in some way, which will depend on the particulars of that plugin (with which I'm not personally familiar).

Comment: Note that you're perfectly free to make such modifications, but by doing so you (potentially) set yourself up for future maintenance work when updates & revisions become available for the plugin.